# Need to click on button twice for javascript function to provide output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, google-maps

im trying to get state code using reverse geolocation and Google API but not getting string output on 1st click. On the second click it appears that result was already there. How do I get it to show up the 1st time i click the button? Been stuck on this for a while.

Javascript:

```
var distance="";
function RetrieveState() {
    geocoder2 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-41.495839, 147.172006);

    distance += " State is: "

    if (geocoder2) {geocoder2.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results,     status)
    {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
       {
           var result = results[0];
           for (var i = 0, len = result.address_components.length; i < len; i++) {
               var ac = result.address_components[i];
               if (ac.types.indexOf("administrative_area_level_1") >= 0) 
                  distance +=  ac.short_name; 
           }
        }       
    }
}

document.getElementById("distance_road").innerHTML = distance;
} // end RetrieveState
```

---

button created via ASP:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button 2"  OnClientClick="RetrieveState()" />
```

---

output:
1st click: State is:
2nd click: State is: TAS State is:
3rd click: State is: TAS State is: TAS State is:

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because you're not setting the innerHTML within the `geocode` callback function - this means that you're setting the innerHTML **before** the geocode result is returned. Move the line:

```
document.getElementById("distance_road").innerHTML = distance;
```

to the end of the following `if` statement:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in first time distance variable is set and due to it is global when code execute second time it is displaing, try below code.

```
var distance="";
    function RetrieveState() {
        geocoder2 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-41.495839, 147.172006);

        distance += " State is: "

        if (geocoder2) {geocoder2.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results,     status)
        {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
           {
               var result = results[0];
               for (var i = 0, len = result.address_components.length; i < len; i++) {
                   var ac = result.address_components[i];
                   if (ac.types.indexOf("administrative_area_level_1") >= 0) 
                      distance +=  ac.short_name; 
               }
              document.getElementById("distance_road").innerHTML = distance;
           // end RetrieveState
            }       
        }
    }
  }
```